# Are Nikon teleconverters compatible with the Quantaray 70-300mm telephoto lens

Tags: nikon

I have a Quantaray 70-300mm lens on a Nikon D80 body.  Would the Nikon AF-S teleconverters be compatible with this combination?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an f4-F5.6 lens the teleconverter will not work properly.  The effective aperture with the tc is over f5.6.  The camera needs an aperture of f5.6 or less to autofocus properly.

Comment: It could possibly work using manual focus. Most Quantaray lenses are manual focus only anyway, having been made in the pre-AF era.

Comment: Michael C.  That's not accurate.   Most Quantaray lenses were sold during the AF era when David had between 500 and 1000 stores.  I know.   I was there.   Ritz sold countless AF Quantaray lenses.

Comment: I'll take your word for it. I seem to remember seeing a lot more Quantaray stuff advertised in the early to mid 1980s that in the 1990. I shopped more at Wolf than Ritz back then. I had a friend who was a district manager for Wolf when the Wolf bankruptcy and buyout by Ritz took place in 2001.

Comment: Yep, David gave his cousin hundreds of stores and they made sure they didn't compete w/ each other, but Wolf never seemed to stabilize even though they were almost identical.  David bought out hundreds of small town camera shops then bought back Wolf then folded.  He single handedly destroyed small camera shops in the US.  Walmart is blamed quite often but Ritz did the most damage.   Both Ritz and Wolf seemed to be constantly doing damage control.   I'm surprised Boaters World still has a store in Florida.

Comment: Chuck Wolf bought nine Ritz stores from his uncle Edward, David's father, and founded Wolf Camera in 1974 four years before David took over the reigns of Ritz from his father in 1978. All of Wolf's stores were expanded from those nine. David gave his cousin nothing but a cheap buyout at pennies on the dollar when Wolf went bankrupt in 2001. By all accounts I've heard, Chuck was a lot better to work for than David.